# Getting current sorted column in DataTable

Tags: datatables

I remember once I used some API to get table's sorted column info but I couldn't find now. I want to find which column currently is used for sorted and in which order? Since I am using both legacy and new DataTable in different project in different company I will appreciate if some one can provide PAI for both version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your table has an id of `mytable`

```
var sortedCol = $('#mytable').dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting[0][0];
var sortedDir = $('#mytable').dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current ordering of the table:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var order = table.order();
```

you will get array of order